# Prioritize Windows driver start up order

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I would like to know if there is a way to prioritize certain drivers before other start up executables are loaded at log in. For e.g.: I would like to load my trackpad driver before anything actually loads on Windows 7/8, because its one of the ELAN trackpads and is not functional unless the driver is loaded and I have to wait like a minute before that happens

Comment: Do you know whether it has a Windows Service attached to it? If so, you could play with dependencies, making something like `winlogon` dependent on that service running.

Comment: Try setting a bunch of Windows services to [Delayed Start](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/delayed-start-feature-increases-options-for-windows-services/1552). That may reduce I/O load enough that the driver can load more quickly during bootup.

Answer (score 1):

For programs there is Start-Q, it is no longer available on the developers website [but I found it here](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=52118) where it can be downloaded, use the mirror link on the page.

[Read about it here](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/02/14/optimize-windows-startup-programs-with-start-q/)

Basically you set different delay times for each startup item, this way you can control the order in which they load.